# vuejs not showing the value inside {{ }} , the text is displayed as it is

Tags: vue.js

I developed a vuejs program and run the `npx serve` command. I go to the directory and run npx serve. I browse the `http://localhost:300/myvuefile.html` , I get the following output only.
{{count}} inside the button. My code :

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="count++">{{ count }}</button>
</div>

<script>
import { createApp } from 'vue'

const app = createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  }
})

app.mount('#app')
</script>
```

I have to get the value of the count and onclick the count should increment. Instead I get the output as {{count}} only. Please help to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#using-vue-from-cdn)-

> When using the global build of Vue, all top-level APIs
> are exposed as properties on the global Vue object.

So, either use like this-

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  }
})

app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <button @click="count++">{{ count }}</button>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
```

Or use like this-

```js
const { createApp } = Vue

const app = createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  }
})

app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <button @click="count++">{{ count }}</button>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
```

Comment: Basically the problem is that it's not possible to use `import from 'vue'` when using a CDN link. There is not Vue package installed. As you mentionned, it has to be used from the globally exposed `Vue` object (the capital letter is important).

Comment: Yes, you are right. I meant the same to using Vue global property when using via CDN. Should I edit the answer, if it's not clear?

Comment: As you want, but it's fine. I just wanted to bring more context on why this anwser is correct :)

Comment: I saved the code to an html file and tried to run it in the browser by opening the html file in the browser and also tried npx run in the directory and pointed the browser to http://localhost:3000/myfile.html . The browser displays a button with {{count}} only

Comment: Make sure that the CDN script is imported before the script of code.

Comment: My code test.html: ```<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<script>
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  }
})

app.mount('#app')
</script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="count++">{{ count }}</button>
</div> ```